# In assembly, how do I look for a symbol from one string in another string?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I need to make and Assembly program that looks for repeating substrings in a string, but my program just looks through the whole string without finding a match. How do fix it?

The code itself (don't mind the comments in cyrillic):

```
section '.data' data readable writable                  ;секция данных

string db 'Hello world',0                                   ;исходная строка
substring db 'orl',0                                        ;искомая строка
output db "The substring was encountered %d times", 0       ;текст сообщения

section '.code' code readable writable executable       ;секция кода

start:
        cld                     ;очищаем флаг направления DF
        xor ebx, ebx            ;очищаем EBX как счётчик подстрок
        mov esi, string         ;перемещаем строку в ESI
        mov edx, substring      ;перемещаем искомую подстроку в EDX
        mov ecx, 11             ;перемещаем длину строки в ECX
        cmp byte [esi],0        ;если строка закончилась, переходим на FINISH
        je FINISH
        cmp byte [edi],0        ;если подстрока закончилась, переходим на FINISH
        je FINISH
        
SEARCH:     
        mov al, [edx]           ;перемещаем первый символ искомой подстроки в AL
        repnz scasb             ;пока символы строки не совпадают с данным символом подстроки, проходим
        jcxz FINISH             ;если строка закончилась, переходим на FINISH
        
CHECK:
        inc edx                 ;переходим на следующий символ подстроки
        cmp byte [edx], 0           ;проверяем, закончилась ли искомая подстрока
        jz FOUND                ;если конец искомой подстроки, переходим на FOUND
        inc esi                 ;переходим на следующий символ строки
        dec ecx                 ;уменьшаем ECX на 1
        jcxz FINISH             ;если строка закончилась, переходим на FINISH
        mov al, [edx]           ;перемещаем следующий символ искомой подстроки в AL
        cmp byte [esi], al      ;проверяем текущий символ строки
        jne SEARCH              ;если символы не равны, переходим на SEARCH
        jmp CHECK               ;если символы равны, переходим на CHECK
        
FOUND:
        inc ebx                 ;увеличиваем EBX
        inc esi                 ;переходим на следующий символ строки
        dec ecx                 ;уменьшаем ECX на 1
        jcxz FINISH             ;если строка закончилась, переходим на FINISH
        jmp SEARCH              ;переходим на SEARCH
        
FINISH:
        
        
        
    ccall [printf], output, ebx
    ccall [getchar]
    stdcall [ExitProcess],0
```

Comment: Did you try single stepping?  Hint: verify `edi`?

Comment: @ErikEidt But I'm using `edi`. Also, what do you mean "verify"?

Comment: He means, you have a typo at `mov edx, substring` because your comment says it should be `edi`.

Comment: @Jester I forgot to change the comment, sorry.

Comment: Then you also need to change `cmp byte [edi],0` to `edx` because `edi` is not set to anything.

Comment: Anyway, the worse problem is that you do not reset it back to the substring once a potential match turns out to be false.

Comment: What about the `scasb`?

Comment: What I mean by verify is: when you single step in the debugger, look at the registers  to see if they have values you want.

Comment: @ErikEidt: `scasb` is just a peephole optimization (for code-size, not speed) for a compare and pointer increment.  It's just one extra thing to understand beyond the basic building blocks of simple instructions.  Even `repne scasb` (memchr in a can) is nothing you can't do manually and just about as fast; only `rep movs` / `rep stos` have fast strings microcode in modern CPUs.  If you want fast, might look for a matching 2-byte sequence with `pcmpeqw` if that can be made efficient without missing corner cases.

Comment: @PeterCordes, there was a discussion about `edi`, and the code uses `scasb`.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Oh, I see, didn't notice the code already uses `repne scasb`, just skimmed upvoted comments >.<.  IIRC `jcxz` to look at the low 2 bytes of ECX fails to distinguish between the last byte matching or not; `je` to branch on FLAGS would do that.  (It's also really weird to use `jcxz` instead of `jecxz` in 32-bit code.)